# storing dataset of entire table and doing query on copy then updating GridView with results of query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to n-tier enterprise development. I just got quite a tutorial just reading threw the 'questions that may already have your answer' but didn't find what I was looking for. I'm doing a geneology site that starts off with the first guy that came over on the boat, you click on his name and the grid gets populated with all his children, then click on one of his kids that has kids and the grid gets populated with his kids and so forth. Each record has an ID and a ParentID. When you choose any given person, the ID is stored and then used in a search for all records that match the ParentID which returns all the kids. The data is never changed (at least by the user) so I want to just do one database access, fill all fields into one datatable and then do a requery of it each time to get the records to display. In the DAL I put all the records into a List which, in the ObjectDataSource the function that fills the GridView just returns the List of all entries. What I want to do is requery the datatable, fill the list back up with the new query and display in the GridView. My code is in 3 files [here](http://www.hampleman.com/source)

(I can't get the backticks to show my code in this window) All I need is to figure out how to make a new query on the existing DataTable and copy it to a new DataTable. Hope this explains it well enough.
[edit: It would be easier to just do a new query from the database each time and it would be less resource intensive (in the future if the database gets too large) to store in memory, but I just want to know if I can do it this way - that is, working from 1 copy of the entire table] Any ideas...

Comment: Serving a .cs file from a .net site is prohibited by design. Your code demo in the link can't be read as a result...

Answer (score 0):

Your data represents a tree structure by nature. 
A grid to display it may not be my first choice...

Querying all data in one query can be done by using a complex SP.

But you are already considering performance. Thats always a good thing to keep in mind when coming up with a design. But creating something, improve it and only then start to optimize seems a better to go.

Since relational databases are not real good on hierarchical data, consider a nosql (graph)database. As you mentioned there are almost no writes to the DB, nosql shines here.

Comment: I just went to wikipedia and was reading about nosql briefly. I only have MSSQL on my hosting service and I was also going to have another table or 2 that lists all the related documents and pictures to show a picture and bio to go with any selected entry. I thought about using and XML file which might also be an approach for a hierarchy type db.